# K-medoids clustering using precomputed matric

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I want to perform Gower clustering (on mixed binary and non-binary data) and then perform K-medoids clustering based on the distance matrix `dm`.

```
import gower
from sklearn_extra.cluster import KMedoids

dft = df.T
X = dft.iloc[:-5,:]
y = dft.iloc[-5:,:]

mms = MinMaxScaler()
mms.fit(X)
data_transformed = mms.transform(X)

dm = gower_matrix(X, y)

K = range(1, 10)
for k in K:
    kmedoids = KMedoids(n_clusters=k, metric="precomputed", method="pam").fit(dm, y)
```

Traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [33], in <cell line: 1>()
      1 for k in K:
----> 3     kmedoids = KMedoids(n_clusters=k, metric="precomputed", method="pam").fit(dm, y)
      5     distortions.append(sum(np.min(cdist(dm, kmedoids.cluster_centers_,'euclidean'), axis=1)) / dm.shape[0])
      6     inertias.append(kmedoids.inertia_)

File ~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn_extra/cluster/_k_medoids.py:196, in KMedoids.fit(self, X, y)
    189 if self.n_clusters > X.shape[0]:
    190     raise ValueError(
    191         "The number of medoids (%d) must be less "
    192         "than the number of samples %d."
    193         % (self.n_clusters, X.shape[0])
    194     )
--> 196 D = pairwise_distances(X, metric=self.metric)
    197 medoid_idxs = self._initialize_medoids(
    198     D, self.n_clusters, random_state_
    199 )
    200 labels = None

File /scg/apps/software/jupyter/python_3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/pairwise.py:1851, in pairwise_distances(X, Y, metric, n_jobs, force_all_finite, **kwds)
   1845     raise ValueError(
   1846         "Unknown metric %s. Valid metrics are %s, or 'precomputed', or a callable"
   1847         % (metric, _VALID_METRICS)
   1848     )
   1850 if metric == "precomputed":
-> 1851     X, _ = check_pairwise_arrays(
   1852         X, Y, precomputed=True, force_all_finite=force_all_finite
   1853     )
   1855     whom = (
   1856         "`pairwise_distances`. Precomputed distance "
   1857         " need to have non-negative values."
   1858     )
   1859     check_non_negative(X, whom=whom)

File /scg/apps/software/jupyter/python_3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/pairwise.py:175, in check_pairwise_arrays(X, Y, precomputed, dtype, accept_sparse, force_all_finite, copy)
    173 if precomputed:
    174     if X.shape[1] != Y.shape[0]:
--> 175         raise ValueError(
    176             "Precomputed metric requires shape "
    177             "(n_queries, n_indexed). Got (%d, %d) "
    178             "for %d indexed." % (X.shape[0], X.shape[1], Y.shape[0])
    179         )
    180 elif X.shape[1] != Y.shape[1]:
    181     raise ValueError(
    182         "Incompatible dimension for X and Y matrices: "
    183         "X.shape[1] == %d while Y.shape[1] == %d" % (X.shape[1], Y.shape[1])
    184     )

ValueError: Precomputed metric requires shape (n_queries, n_indexed). Got (202, 5) for 202 indexed.
```

Data:

`df.iloc[1:200,0:3]`

```
pd.DataFrame({'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': {'IGF2R': 0,
  'NBEA': 0,
  'KMT2D': 0,
  'HERC2': 0,
  'NEB': 0,
  'TTN': 0,
  'SF3B1': 0,
  'DNAH5': 1,
  'MDN1': 0,
  'MET': 0,
  'LRP6': 0,
  'EML5': 0,
  'RYR3': 0,
  'COL18A1': 0,
  'EP300': 0,
  'GLS': 0,
  'CUL3': 0,
  'MUC17': 0,
  'WDR81': 0,
  'TP53': 0,
  'SSH2': 0,
  'RYR1': 0,
  'CSMD2': 0,
  'NFE2L2': 0,
  'PKHD1': 0,
  'MON2': 0,
  'PARD6B': 0,
  'KIF1B': 0,
  'FLG': 0,
  'BIRC6': 0,
  'VCAN': 0,
  'SYNE1': 0,
  'TG': 0,
  'ANK3': 0,
  'FANCM': 0,
  'DMXL2': 0,
  'SRCAP': 0,
  'ZZEF1': 0,
  'KDM6A': 0,
  'STAG2': 0,
  'ARID1A': 0,
  'SMARCA4': 0,
  'RERE': 0,
  'DST': 0,
  'AHCTF1': 0,
  'CENPE': 0,
  'GRAMD1A': 0,
  'SMC6': 0,
  'WDFY3': 0,
  'SLC5A12': 0,
  'TENM3': 0,
  'RYR2': 0,
  'BRCA2': 0,
  'CLTC': 0,
  'HELZ2': 0,
  'SETD2': 0,
  'BAP1': 0,
  'PRAG1': 0,
  'NF2': 0,
  'UBR3': 0,
  'MACF1': 0,
  'KMT2C': 0,
  'PRR12': 0,
  'RANBP2': 1,
  'GBF1': 0,
  'CHD8': 0,
  'SYNE2': 0,
  'SMG1': 0,
  'TSC2': 0,
  'ARHGEF28': 0,
  'KIAA1109': 0,
  'TET1': 0,
  'MYT1': 0,
  'SMARCB1': 0,
  'LRP2': 0,
  'LRP1B': 0,
  'MUC16': 0,
  'SAV1': 0,
  'DIP2C': 0,
  'PCF11': 0,
  'XIRP2': 0,
  'DNAH1': 0,
  'DNAH8': 0,
  'CSMD3': 0,
  'TLN1': 0,
  'DYNC1H1': 0,
  'SHANK3': 0,
  'LRBA': 0,
  'CNOT1': 0,
  'CEP250': 0,
  'PRRC2C': 0,
  'SRRM2': 0,
  'POLR1A': 0,
  'ADGRV1': 0,
  'ZAN': 0,
  'MED13': 0,
  'PBRM1': 0,
  'PCLO': 0,
  'CACNA1S': 0,
  'FAT1': 0,
  'NUP214': 0,
  'ATXN2': 0,
  'AHNAK': 0,
  'XRN1': 0,
  'BOD1L1': 0,
  'TEP1': 0,
  'UNC13A': 0,
  'SZT2': 0,
  'USH2A': 0,
  'GOLGB1': 0,
  'ANK2': 0,
  'UBR4': 0,
  'HMCN1': 0,
  'PTEN': 0,
  'MYH4': 0,
  'CNTNAP5': 0,
  'APOB': 0,
  'SPATA31D1': 0,
  'DDX5': 0,
  'DSCAM': 0,
  'ATP1B1': 0,
  'PLEKHA6': 0,
  'LRIG3': 0,
  'ACSF2': 0,
  'CPLANE1': 0,
  'GOLGA4': 0,
  'TNRC18': 0,
  'OBSCN': 0,
  'CUBN': 0,
  'NIPBL': 0,
  'HERC1': 0,
  'CREBBP': 0,
  'CENPF': 0,
  'TNRC6A': 0,
  'MYOM2': 0,
  'ARHGAP32': 0,
  'VPS13C': 0,
  'F12': 0,
  'KAT6A': 1,
  'DYNC2H1': 0,
  'CLUH': 0,
  'KNL1': 0,
  'MEGF8': 1,
  'JMJD1C': 0,
  'FREM2': 0,
  'SPEN': 0,
  'hsa-let-7a-5p': 3.900520072456484,
  'hsa-let-7a-3p': 1.7954225750902864,
  'hsa-let-7b-5p': 3.684774825723109,
  'hsa-let-7b-3p': 1.8237020381693356,
  'hsa-let-7c-5p': 3.519438691136673,
  'hsa-let-7d-5p': 2.889577781432674,
  'hsa-let-7d-3p': 3.0524182512860767,
  'hsa-let-7e-5p': 3.24169139997674,
  'hsa-let-7f-5p': 3.806804681066821,
  'hsa-miR-15a-5p': 2.8873344760439683,
  'hsa-miR-16-5p': 3.169448223239302,
  'hsa-miR-17-5p': 2.9038686633461497,
  'hsa-miR-17-3p': 3.002610000350878,
  'hsa-miR-19b-3p': 2.4763377001511224,
  'hsa-miR-20a-5p': 2.8294381272239373,
  'hsa-miR-21-5p': 4.231168046714244,
  'hsa-miR-21-3p': 3.3505095806399603,
  'hsa-miR-22-5p': 2.3380346380813744,
  'hsa-miR-22-3p': 4.100304205695363,
  'hsa-miR-23a-3p': 3.5631194957307266,
  'hsa-miR-24-1-5p': -0.5174965677416278,
  'hsa-miR-24-3p': 3.4240942526453217,
  'hsa-miR-24-2-5p': 1.9897204362031105,
  'hsa-miR-25-3p': 3.6011473778864613,
  'hsa-miR-26a-5p': 3.459216786355344,
  'hsa-miR-26b-5p': 3.244044676182424,
  'hsa-miR-26b-3p': 2.1772832419542314,
  'hsa-miR-27a-3p': 3.330214050573812,
  'hsa-miR-28-5p': 2.8084680302131613,
  'hsa-miR-28-3p': 3.445835549140937,
  'hsa-miR-29a-5p': 1.4322013458364455,
  'hsa-miR-29a-3p': 3.747380534542168,
  'hsa-miR-30a-5p': 4.034264831009016,
  'hsa-miR-30a-3p': 3.86192271659328,
  'hsa-miR-32-5p': 2.2457925142206228,
  'hsa-miR-92a-3p': 3.622342073475701,
  'hsa-miR-93-5p': 3.4862692022139234,
  'hsa-miR-98-5p': 2.673648173443926,
  'hsa-miR-99a-5p': 3.306517273383935,
  'hsa-miR-100-5p': 3.56281613854454,
  'hsa-miR-101-3p': 3.823911869890638,
  'hsa-miR-29b-3p': 3.225462772887926,
  'hsa-miR-29b-2-5p': 2.387517043267465,
  'hsa-miR-103a-3p': 3.913516891372183,
  'hsa-miR-106a-5p': 1.5947921744868148,
  'hsa-miR-107': 2.765560153240496,
  'hsa-miR-192-5p': 3.444283905581549,
  'hsa-miR-196a-5p': 2.8748375476624948,
  'hsa-miR-197-3p': 3.2702909773912223,
  'hsa-miR-199a-5p': 2.4174982443909765,
  'hsa-miR-199a-3p': 2.7699786837570124,
  'hsa-miR-148a-3p': 3.783478829387657,
  'hsa-miR-30c-5p': 3.242366731126448},
 'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': {'IGF2R': 1,
  'NBEA': 1,
  'KMT2D': 0,
  'HERC2': 0,
  'NEB': 0,
  'TTN': 0,
  'SF3B1': 0,
  'DNAH5': 0,
  'MDN1': 0,
  'MET': 0,
  'LRP6': 0,
  'EML5': 0,
  'RYR3': 0,
  'COL18A1': 0,
  'EP300': 0,
  'GLS': 0,
  'CUL3': 0,
  'MUC17': 0,
  'WDR81': 0,
  'TP53': 0,
  'SSH2': 0,
  'RYR1': 0,
  'CSMD2': 0,
  'NFE2L2': 0,
  'PKHD1': 0,
  'MON2': 0,
  'PARD6B': 0,
  'KIF1B': 0,
  'FLG': 0,
  'BIRC6': 0,
  'VCAN': 0,
  'SYNE1': 0,
  'TG': 0,
  'ANK3': 0,
  'FANCM': 0,
  'DMXL2': 0,
  'SRCAP': 0,
  'ZZEF1': 0,
  'KDM6A': 0,
  'STAG2': 0,
  'ARID1A': 0,
  'SMARCA4': 0,
  'RERE': 0,
  'DST': 0,
  'AHCTF1': 0,
  'CENPE': 0,
  'GRAMD1A': 0,
  'SMC6': 0,
  'WDFY3': 0,
  'SLC5A12': 0,
  'TENM3': 0,
  'RYR2': 0,
  'BRCA2': 0,
  'CLTC': 0,
  'HELZ2': 0,
  'SETD2': 0,
  'BAP1': 0,
  'PRAG1': 0,
  'NF2': 0,
  'UBR3': 0,
  'MACF1': 0,
  'KMT2C': 0,
  'PRR12': 0,
  'RANBP2': 0,
  'GBF1': 0,
  'CHD8': 0,
  'SYNE2': 0,
  'SMG1': 0,
  'TSC2': 0,
  'ARHGEF28': 0,
  'KIAA1109': 0,
  'TET1': 0,
  'MYT1': 0,
  'SMARCB1': 0,
  'LRP2': 0,
  'LRP1B': 0,
  'MUC16': 0,
  'SAV1': 0,
  'DIP2C': 0,
  'PCF11': 0,
  'XIRP2': 0,
  'DNAH1': 0,
  'DNAH8': 0,
  'CSMD3': 0,
  'TLN1': 0,
  'DYNC1H1': 0,
  'SHANK3': 0,
  'LRBA': 0,
  'CNOT1': 0,
  'CEP250': 0,
  'PRRC2C': 0,
  'SRRM2': 0,
  'POLR1A': 0,
  'ADGRV1': 0,
  'ZAN': 0,
  'MED13': 0,
  'PBRM1': 0,
  'PCLO': 0,
  'CACNA1S': 0,
  'FAT1': 0,
  'NUP214': 0,
  'ATXN2': 0,
  'AHNAK': 0,
  'XRN1': 0,
  'BOD1L1': 0,
  'TEP1': 0,
  'UNC13A': 0,
  'SZT2': 0,
  'USH2A': 0,
  'GOLGB1': 0,
  'ANK2': 0,
  'UBR4': 0,
  'HMCN1': 0,
  'PTEN': 0,
  'MYH4': 0,
  'CNTNAP5': 0,
  'APOB': 0,
  'SPATA31D1': 0,
  'DDX5': 0,
  'DSCAM': 0,
  'ATP1B1': 0,
  'PLEKHA6': 0,
  'LRIG3': 0,
  'ACSF2': 0,
  'CPLANE1': 0,
  'GOLGA4': 0,
  'TNRC18': 0,
  'OBSCN': 0,
  'CUBN': 0,
  'NIPBL': 0,
  'HERC1': 0,
  'CREBBP': 0,
  'CENPF': 0,
  'TNRC6A': 0,
  'MYOM2': 0,
  'ARHGAP32': 0,
  'VPS13C': 0,
  'F12': 0,
  'KAT6A': 0,
  'DYNC2H1': 0,
  'CLUH': 0,
  'KNL1': 0,
  'MEGF8': 0,
  'JMJD1C': 0,
  'FREM2': 0,
  'SPEN': 0,
  'hsa-let-7a-5p': 3.861192885173194,
  'hsa-let-7a-3p': 2.436967295678264,
  'hsa-let-7b-5p': 3.6676128143486753,
  'hsa-let-7b-3p': 1.958120697018377,
  'hsa-let-7c-5p': 3.3710754357912336,
  'hsa-let-7d-5p': 2.889071049014615,
  'hsa-let-7d-3p': 3.0465318021072383,
  'hsa-let-7e-5p': 3.338231516941466,
  'hsa-let-7f-5p': 3.740974488020681,
  'hsa-miR-15a-5p': 2.7906022803335286,
  'hsa-miR-16-5p': 3.057024158120857,
  'hsa-miR-17-5p': 3.029640730993288,
  'hsa-miR-17-3p': 3.1058198055705417,
  'hsa-miR-19b-3p': 2.818744239381312,
  'hsa-miR-20a-5p': 2.962076181923545,
  'hsa-miR-21-5p': 4.227227158408038,
  'hsa-miR-21-3p': 3.442330003846007,
  'hsa-miR-22-5p': 2.500159690761942,
  'hsa-miR-22-3p': 4.057262683406518,
  'hsa-miR-23a-3p': 3.643252279968008,
  'hsa-miR-24-1-5p': 2.078515470188888,
  'hsa-miR-24-3p': 3.520481477727354,
  'hsa-miR-24-2-5p': 2.431900857024301,
  'hsa-miR-25-3p': 3.663267809778581,
  'hsa-miR-26a-5p': 3.5146580089710038,
  'hsa-miR-26b-5p': 3.338697106675036,
  'hsa-miR-26b-3p': 2.1201724506034294,
  'hsa-miR-27a-3p': 3.570982413178969,
  'hsa-miR-28-5p': 2.764316255528613,
  'hsa-miR-28-3p': 3.5004439598626447,
  'hsa-miR-29a-5p': 1.16677801013214,
  'hsa-miR-29a-3p': 3.810914304779572,
  'hsa-miR-30a-5p': 4.066145798006805,
  'hsa-miR-30a-3p': 3.8994855613210233,
  'hsa-miR-32-5p': 2.456425423115635,
  'hsa-miR-92a-3p': 3.7222157388346138,
  'hsa-miR-93-5p': 3.5301163501931785,
  'hsa-miR-98-5p': 2.470234592223246,
  'hsa-miR-99a-5p': 3.261243017454502,
  'hsa-miR-100-5p': 3.446610715459669,
  'hsa-miR-101-3p': 3.7492013918013103,
  'hsa-miR-29b-3p': 3.215998607821593,
  'hsa-miR-29b-2-5p': 2.055762962193227,
  'hsa-miR-103a-3p': 3.848989613004589,
  'hsa-miR-106a-5p': 1.310085727835549,
  'hsa-miR-107': 2.741793996998357,
  'hsa-miR-192-5p': 3.7004707413610975,
  'hsa-miR-196a-5p': 3.240131922656889,
  'hsa-miR-197-3p': 3.067231910554075,
  'hsa-miR-199a-5p': 2.733243180896706,
  'hsa-miR-199a-3p': 2.945706768544072,
  'hsa-miR-148a-3p': 3.653025536010717,
  'hsa-miR-30c-5p': 3.445354673139307},
 'TCGA-2Z-A9J3-01A': {'IGF2R': 0,
  'NBEA': 0,
  'KMT2D': 0,
  'HERC2': 0,
  'NEB': 0,
  'TTN': 0,
  'SF3B1': 0,
  'DNAH5': 0,
  'MDN1': 0,
  'MET': 0,
  'LRP6': 0,
  'EML5': 0,
  'RYR3': 0,
  'COL18A1': 0,
  'EP300': 0,
  'GLS': 0,
  'CUL3': 0,
  'MUC17': 0,
  'WDR81': 0,
  'TP53': 0,
  'SSH2': 0,
  'RYR1': 0,
  'CSMD2': 0,
  'NFE2L2': 0,
  'PKHD1': 0,
  'MON2': 0,
  'PARD6B': 0,
  'KIF1B': 1,
  'FLG': 0,
  'BIRC6': 0,
  'VCAN': 0,
  'SYNE1': 0,
  'TG': 0,
  'ANK3': 0,
  'FANCM': 0,
  'DMXL2': 1,
  'SRCAP': 0,
  'ZZEF1': 0,
  'KDM6A': 0,
  'STAG2': 0,
  'ARID1A': 0,
  'SMARCA4': 0,
  'RERE': 0,
  'DST': 0,
  'AHCTF1': 0,
  'CENPE': 0,
  'GRAMD1A': 0,
  'SMC6': 0,
  'WDFY3': 0,
  'SLC5A12': 0,
  'TENM3': 0,
  'RYR2': 0,
  'BRCA2': 0,
  'CLTC': 0,
  'HELZ2': 0,
  'SETD2': 0,
  'BAP1': 0,
  'PRAG1': 0,
  'NF2': 0,
  'UBR3': 0,
  'MACF1': 0,
  'KMT2C': 0,
  'PRR12': 0,
  'RANBP2': 0,
  'GBF1': 1,
  'CHD8': 0,
  'SYNE2': 1,
  'SMG1': 0,
  'TSC2': 0,
  'ARHGEF28': 0,
  'KIAA1109': 0,
  'TET1': 0,
  'MYT1': 0,
  'SMARCB1': 0,
  'LRP2': 0,
  'LRP1B': 0,
  'MUC16': 0,
  'SAV1': 0,
  'DIP2C': 0,
  'PCF11': 0,
  'XIRP2': 0,
  'DNAH1': 0,
  'DNAH8': 0,
  'CSMD3': 0,
  'TLN1': 0,
  'DYNC1H1': 0,
  'SHANK3': 0,
  'LRBA': 0,
  'CNOT1': 0,
  'CEP250': 0,
  'PRRC2C': 0,
  'SRRM2': 0,
  'POLR1A': 0,
  'ADGRV1': 0,
  'ZAN': 0,
  'MED13': 0,
  'PBRM1': 0,
  'PCLO': 0,
  'CACNA1S': 0,
  'FAT1': 0,
  'NUP214': 1,
  'ATXN2': 0,
  'AHNAK': 0,
  'XRN1': 1,
  'BOD1L1': 1,
  'TEP1': 1,
  'UNC13A': 1,
  'SZT2': 0,
  'USH2A': 0,
  'GOLGB1': 0,
  'ANK2': 0,
  'UBR4': 0,
  'HMCN1': 0,
  'PTEN': 0,
  'MYH4': 0,
  'CNTNAP5': 0,
  'APOB': 0,
  'SPATA31D1': 0,
  'DDX5': 0,
  'DSCAM': 0,
  'ATP1B1': 0,
  'PLEKHA6': 0,
  'LRIG3': 0,
  'ACSF2': 0,
  'CPLANE1': 0,
  'GOLGA4': 0,
  'TNRC18': 0,
  'OBSCN': 0,
  'CUBN': 0,
  'NIPBL': 0,
  'HERC1': 0,
  'CREBBP': 0,
  'CENPF': 0,
  'TNRC6A': 0,
  'MYOM2': 0,
  'ARHGAP32': 0,
  'VPS13C': 0,
  'F12': 0,
  'KAT6A': 0,
  'DYNC2H1': 0,
  'CLUH': 0,
  'KNL1': 0,
  'MEGF8': 0,
  'JMJD1C': 0,
  'FREM2': 0,
  'SPEN': 0,
  'hsa-let-7a-5p': 3.8633445895677534,
  'hsa-let-7a-3p': 1.8616291060705468,
  'hsa-let-7b-5p': 3.5952286310865538,
  'hsa-let-7b-3p': 1.7737597007222166,
  'hsa-let-7c-5p': 3.4958162915921864,
  'hsa-let-7d-5p': 2.813404761324024,
  'hsa-let-7d-3p': 2.856133322589684,
  'hsa-let-7e-5p': 3.4123362083155007,
  'hsa-let-7f-5p': 3.756886844881003,
  'hsa-miR-15a-5p': 2.653398804318862,
  'hsa-miR-16-5p': 2.921140087273342,
  'hsa-miR-17-5p': 2.9080161647528446,
  'hsa-miR-17-3p': 3.0190101751309406,
  'hsa-miR-19b-3p': 2.480118996139677,
  'hsa-miR-20a-5p': 2.891742608011878,
  'hsa-miR-21-5p': 4.243501026965872,
  'hsa-miR-21-3p': 3.3603686240008086,
  'hsa-miR-22-5p': 1.7812090487442638,
  'hsa-miR-22-3p': 3.895577061008923,
  'hsa-miR-23a-3p': 3.5647202862065206,
  'hsa-miR-24-1-5p': 1.2851898171850389,
  'hsa-miR-24-3p': 3.501409872615561,
  'hsa-miR-24-2-5p': 1.758460793518147,
  'hsa-miR-25-3p': 3.623862330680501,
  'hsa-miR-26a-5p': 3.295878145092404,
  'hsa-miR-26b-5p': 3.064662865081599,
  'hsa-miR-26b-3p': 1.325302271821943,
  'hsa-miR-27a-3p': 3.443832233436177,
  'hsa-miR-28-5p': 2.848221798544944,
  'hsa-miR-28-3p': 3.4708383926521824,
  'hsa-miR-29a-5p': 1.5899199958930694,
  'hsa-miR-29a-3p': 3.7701639464079206,
  'hsa-miR-30a-5p': 4.071110462975572,
  'hsa-miR-30a-3p': 3.888012759366865,
  'hsa-miR-32-5p': 2.1380008457637745,
  'hsa-miR-92a-3p': 3.610711811379474,
  'hsa-miR-93-5p': 3.613165791702674,
  'hsa-miR-98-5p': 2.4393265534195563,
  'hsa-miR-99a-5p': 3.3070455119581856,
  'hsa-miR-100-5p': 3.2005876993544486,
  'hsa-miR-101-3p': 3.6838783148428313,
  'hsa-miR-29b-3p': 3.21472389563324,
  'hsa-miR-29b-2-5p': 1.5030824681905002,
  'hsa-miR-103a-3p': 3.8048140947821127,
  'hsa-miR-106a-5p': 0.222868225074613,
  'hsa-miR-107': 2.662719216814865,
  'hsa-miR-192-5p': 3.2684486143788165,
  'hsa-miR-196a-5p': 2.74647744842236,
  'hsa-miR-197-3p': 2.759067800835906,
  'hsa-miR-199a-5p': 1.742599376179338,
  'hsa-miR-199a-3p': 2.301979123150629,
  'hsa-miR-148a-3p': 3.7855708054524713,
  'hsa-miR-30c-5p': 3.3507475510336118}})
```

Comment: can you post some data?

Comment: @seralouk data posted.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce this since you do not provide the data.

I see a lot of problems with your code:

1. `data_transformed` is never used
2. `gower_matrix(X, y)` is applied on the raw `X` matrix
3. you cannot run a kmeans with k=1 `K = range(1, 10)` this is already the case you have, all data belong to one group as they now are.

Here is some code that you can adapt:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from gower import gower_matrix

data = load_iris()
X = data.data
y = data.target

mms = MinMaxScaler()
mms.fit(X)
data_transformed = mms.transform(X)

dm = gower_matrix(data_transformed)

K = range(2, 10)
for k in K:
    kmedoids = KMedoids(n_clusters=k, metric="precomputed", method="pam").fit(dm, y)
```

Comment: I tried your code but it raised `XB must be a 2-dimensional array.`. I added an example data.

Comment: you need to modify the data and you need one column per feature. Now you have dictionaries and `sklearn` works with numpy 2D arrays or pandas df.

Comment: But `dm` is 2d (202,202) array and not a dictionary

Comment: `dm` is all the pairwise distances values. You are the one to choose how to use this information. kmeans will use this to estimate which samples below to the same group